# CORS Missing Allow Origin error .NET Core API when trying to fetch data

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-webapi, fetch-api

I'm new to web programing and am trying to fetch user data from a .NET Core API using JavaScript but I have been getting a CORS Missing Allow Origin error. I'm aware that this is probably a common and easy issue to resolve but I haven't been able to figure out how to do so. And as mentioned in similar questions I also tried it with the "     withCredentials: true" configs for the fetch.

I don't even know at this point whether the issue is server or client side. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

**JavaScipt**

```
function ApiController({id}){
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
        .get('https://localhost:7278/User/'  + id, {
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
        .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch( err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
    }, [id]);
```

**UserController.cs**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// <summary>The user controller.</summary>
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : ControllerBase {

/* 

...

*/

[HttpGet("{userId}")]
public async Task<UserDto> GetUser(Guid userId) {
  return await _userService.GetUser(userId);
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
/*

...

*/

services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => {
      builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
  });

/*

...

*/

app.UseCors(builder =>
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
      .AllowAnyHeader()
      .AllowAnyHeader()
  );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CORS is configured through server-side, so you need to configure on your Server.

Please make sure you enable CORS on the server side, please refer to [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for configuration method.

I did a test on this and your problem didn't appear:

JavaScript(refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-javascript?view=aspnetcore-6.0)):

```
const uri = 'https://localhost:44336/WeatherForecast';
function getItems() {
    fetch(uri, {
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => _displayItems(data))
        .catch(error => console.error('Unable to get items.', error));
}
```

Then, register CORS on the called server side.(refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0)).

Result:

[image]

If the problem persists, you can try passing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from the server's response:

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                context.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
                return next.Invoke();
            });
```

Hope this can help you.